# C++ Input Overload Error

Tags: c++

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, const complex& P) {
        input >> P.real >> P.imaginary;
        return input;
}
```

I have the code above and for some reason I get this error:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'double').
```

complex& P is an object which basically stores the real number part and imaginary number part of a complex number. So if you have 2 + 3i, P.real will return to you back 2 and P.imaginary will return to you back 3. And the real and imaginary numbers are both double.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Remove const from const complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When overloading the >> operator, the variable to which you want to assign the input values has to be mutable, so you need to remove the "const"

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, complex& P) {
  input >> P.real >> P.imaginary;
  return input;
}
```

Comment: yeah just realized that haha... the small errors... Thanks for the help!